# Sharepoint 2010 - Datasheet view and 3 linked lists

Tags: sharepoint, datasheet

I've got a tricky situation I'm trying to determine the best way to solve. I'm a VS developer who is learning SharePoint so it's a little frustrating to me when what I am trying to accomplish could easily be done with code and a db.

I have three lists, a parent and two children list that are linked through lookup columns. The client actually wanted everything in one list but due to SharePoint column type limitations I had to split the data into the three lists, there are over 300 fields. The client wants to see all the lists together in one view and be able to filter and edit groups of items.

I have successfully created a new data source linking the lists and can display that on one of my pages to view. After some research however I have learned that I can't create a datasheet view from this linked view due to limitations in the Office componets that SP uses. Which makes sense.

The business need is for the client to filter the three lists based on criteria they select from either list A AND list B and list C to get a group of items, they make the updates and save the changes back to the 3 lists. They prefer to do this in datasheet view because this mimics the excel spreadsheet that they are currently using that this website will replace. They will potentially be updating between 1-30 items at a time using this, which is why they prefer the drag and copy functionality.

I was thinking of two options: trying to create some kind of custom web part that has a gridview of all the columns in edit mode that they can filter down to their items and make their changes. Then I would have to loop through the fields and make updates programmatically. I also saw on this site jQuery.sheet, that looks like it may be a good solution if I go this route instead of gridview.

Or have a modal window with the columns listed, have the user select what they want to filter to, then redirect to a page that shows the three lists in their own DSVs. The user would have to make updates in the three separate views. Then I would use workflows to synchronize the lists after they had made their changes.

I always end up trying to do things programmatically since I am still largely unfamiliar with SP and only seem to hit its limitations instead of its strengths. Has anyone tried to do something similar to this? Or do you have any suggestions as to the best way to accomplish this? Best practices? I appreciate all thoughts and comments! FYI I've also posted this on the MS SP forums as well to cast a wider net...

Thanks,
Sabrina

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are better off going with a custom solution. A webpart would be an excellent choice for delivering your custom interface. 
A dataview webpart will do the job, but if you feel comfortable with the jQuery solution it would make for a nicer interface.

In your code, treat the lists as you would a database and isolate it from the logic and interface code within the webpart.